# Facebook Connect Log Out

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, session

I am developing a Php based application with CodeIgniter using Facebook Connect SDK for php. So far all users are able to log in into the system but for some when they try to log out the session would not expire! This is really odd since this would work for some users and not work for the others! 
Following is the basic logout code that I use that Facebook provided: 
controller:

```
if ($user) {
            $data['logoutUrl'] = $this->facebook->getLogoutUrl();
```

View:

```
<a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>" id="bstyle" onclick="RemoveSess()">Logout</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
function RemoveSess(){
                $.post("<?php echo base_url(); ?>"+ "/facebook_cn/remSess", function(data){
                        document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = $data;       
                      });   
            }
```

Php Controller:

```
function remSess()
{
    $data2 = array('user_id' => '','logged_in' => '');
    $this->session->unset_userdata($data2);
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    session_destroy();
    $data = array('sess' => "gone" );
    echo json_encode($data["sess"]="gone");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are destroying local session but user will not log out from Facebook with this code. So your application will cache the user's Facebook session as soon as you will init SDK. You need to logout the user from both Facebook and your site or check better login/Facebook connect function to not autologin user.

Provide login function and code where you init Facebook SDK if you need more explanation.

**Update**

This is what I have for FB connect:

```
$this->_facebook = new Facebookapi($settings);

// Try to get the user's id on Facebook
$userId = $this->_facebook->getUser();

// If user is not yet authenticated, the id will be zero
if( $userId == 0 ){
    $this->_loginUrl = $this->_facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>'email')); 
}else{
    $_user = $this->_facebook->api('/me');
    $this->_user = new Users();
    $this->_user->load($_user['username'], 'facebook');
}
```

So if user is logged in facebook I check if I already have user with such username and if yes I load user to object. User will be automatically logged back to my site without need of clicking connect button again.

You need to check your code to sure that you don't have something like I have or your user will never logout until logout from facebook first.

Comment: UAWDT, could you add a little more detail here to make this more clear?  I think I can guess most of what you mean, but I'm not sure.  Also I made some minor edits but there are places where it's not clear what is being said.

Comment: Can you please add your login function and __constructor of controller that handle login/facebook connect function?